# Проблема в создании и вызове функций и процедур в postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Таблица создана,данными заполнена,необходимо реализовать примитивную функцию подсчета строк в данной таблице.Вот,какая у меня функция получилась

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_str(varchar v ) RETURNS bigint AS $$
            BEGIN
                   select count(*) from v;
            END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

не получается ее вызвать,хотя возможно и создана она неправильно,вот так вызываю:

```
    SELECT * from count_str("something");
```

`something` - имя таблицы.

При вызове пишет *"столбец "something" не существует"*

Comment: Тело функции невалидно для plpgsql само по себе - что делать с результатом select? Вы не можете использовать параметр как имя статичного запроса. Вместо этого вам понадобится собрать текст запроса и его выполнить. Ну и сам запрос с вызовом хранимки некорректен, в двойных кавычках пишутся имена таблиц/полей/etc участвующих в запросе. У вас в запросе неоткуда взять объект something

Comment: @SmellyNS не работает,когда обращаюсь к функции пишет,что "отношение "v" не существует"

Comment: @user352034, чуть-чуть освежил память об sql и исправил ответ. Попробуйте снова

Comment: Мой запрос написан на Transact-SQL, вам придется немного поправить синтаксис, если потребуется.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция возвращает **bigint**, но вы пытаетесь обратиться к ней, как к таблице.

То есть ваше обращение эквивалентно следующей строке:

```
select * from 5
```

Попробуйте что-то похожее:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_str(@v table) RETURNS bigint AS $$
            BEGIN
                declare @ret bigint;
                select @ret = count(*) from @v
                return @ret;
            END;
Select count_str(tablename);
```

Comment: `но вы пытаетесь обратиться к ней, как к таблице` - это корректная форма обращения.

Comment: В постгре можно брать выборку из числа? Я работал на транзакт и там такое строго каралось, насколько я помню)

Comment: @Мелкий что, кстати, логично. Нельзя же хэшировать число и индексировать его по первичному ключу и т.д. и т.п.
Можно выбрать само число, но не что-либо из него.

Comment: Для возвращающей скаляр функции func() запрос `from func()` есть логический эквивалент некоторого `from (select func() as func) as subquery`. А для returns setof это основной способ вызова, в отличии от неоднозначного в поведении и потому ограниченного `select srf_func() from ...`.

Comment: Да, я допустил ошибку и исправил ответ. Прошу прощения. Познавательно, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Поробуйте

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_str(v varchar) RETURNS bigint AS $$
DECLARE
    res_count BIGINT;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'select count(*) from ' || v INTO res_count;
    RETURN res_count;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

вызвать

```
SELECT * from count_str("something");
```